# System Center 2012 - Can't Install Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, vhd

Here is my setup:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise (updated to SP2)
- 32GB RAM
- x2 Quad Core Xeon 5500 Series Processors (16 cores total)
- x3 120GB Intel SSDs
- Computer is joined to a domain

I downloaded the evaluation copy of System Center 2012 from Microsoft with the intention of using the SCVMM (Service Center Virtual Machine Manager) to create a VHD from an existing Windows Server 2k3 install.

SO I extracted the SCVMM files and ran Setup.exe.   When the splash/installer screen pops up I click on Install and see the following message

> Virtual Machine Manager server is not supported on this operating
>   system.  For more information, see "Supported Operating Systems for
>   VMM" in Virtual Machine Manager Setup Help.

Now, I am not even sure what this error is referring to as "Virtual Machine Manager Setup Help" considering there are not any items on the installer/splash screen that say that exact phrase or even something similar.

I googled *System Center 2012 Virtual Machine Manager supported operating systems* and as far as I can tell, my operating system is supported!

Here is the SCVMM System Requirements article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg610562.aspx

Here are some of the things I have tried in order to get SCVMM to work

1. Installed .NET 3.5 SP1
2. Installed MSQL Server 2008 R2
3. Installed WinRM v2.0 (and checked to make sure that the service is actually started when I try to install SCVMM)
4. Updated Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 SP2 with all available patches/updates via Windows Update.
5. Installed Windows 7 AIK

One very strange thing I came across when trying to get SCVMM working was in the directory where I extracted the installer files, I noticed there was an amd64 directory with a setup.exe located inside.  I opened up that executable (keep in mind, I have an Intel CPU but the OS is x64) and click on Install and I get the following message:

> You need Administrator privileges to install.  Please log in using an
>   account with local Administrative privileges and run Setup.

Well, that is nice and all, but i get the message regardless if I am logged on locally as the local admin or if I login to the domain with my account (which has local administrative privileges).

What gives?!?!?!?    What am I doing wrong?   Why are the error messages so vague, or even incorrect at times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements:

> Windows Server 2008 R2 (full installation)
>
> Standard, Enterprise, and Datacenter
>
> Service Pack 1 or earlier
>
> x64

Note it says "SP1 or earlier".

You claim you are running 2008 R2 SP2.  The thing is, there (currently) is no SP2 for [2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842).

There IS a [SP2 for 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17669) (R1), which is not a supported OS for SCVMM (see above).

So, are you sure you're not using Windows 2008 R1? :)

Comment: good catch!   Hmm....  I was under the impression I was running R2, but now that I look at the information my system dialog i see WIndows Server Enterporise Service Pack 2.. No Mention of R2.  Would it clearly state that I was running R2 on the Control Panel > System dialog?

Comment: BTW that was totally what the issue was!  thanks again!   I am downloading Windows Server 2008 x64 R2 from an internal purchasing system now.